# embedding python script in php website

Tags: php, python

I am developing a php based web app but I have a python script that I already had that I want to integrate into my system. Is it possible to embed/include the python script within the main content area of my web app on a specific page?

Comment: you could call the script on the command line using exec. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497540/how-to-call-a-python-script-from-php

Comment: Not to beat you up, but it is Python, not phython.

Comment: Thanks for that Jonathan! and sorry! Hadn't realized I spelt it wrong. Some silly spell check lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this app for embedding pythonb code into php [http://www.csh.rit.edu/~jon/projects/pip/](http://www.csh.rit.edu/%7Ejon/projects/pip/)

Answer (score 1):

There's this implementation of python called python server page that you can use to embed python into the web app directly just like php but it would have file extension .psp it is not actively developed, Google it up