# Passing Encryption/Decryption Keys from Python to PHP?

Tags: php, python, encryption

I am using **Python Pycrypto** Module to generate **RSA** key pair:

```
#!/home/user/Desktop/generate_keys.py

from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random

random_generator = Random.new().read
key = RSA.generate(1024,random_generator)
public_key = key.publickey().exportKey()               #export public key
private_key = key.exportKey()                          #export private key

print(public_key)
print(private_key)
```

What I need to do is run the script in Python and passing both of the keys to PHP which stores it in database. I am trying to do pass the variable through executing the python script in shell then taking the output in PHP.

```
<?php

   $command = escapeshellcmd('python3 generate_keys.py');
   $public_key = shell_exec($command);
   echo $public_key;

?>
```

The problem here is I do not understand how to pass variables from Python to PHP, All I am doing is taking the output of one python script into PHP.

If I try to do it in two separate scripts of Python:

for Public Key:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random

random_generator = Random.new().read
key = RSA.generate(1024,random_generator)

print(key.publickey().exportKey())
```

for Private Key:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random

random_generator = Random.new().read
key = RSA.generate(1024,random_generator)

print(key.exportKey())
```

I will get a different key pair each time I run those `random_generator`.

How Can I pass variables of Python `('public_key' & 'private_key')` to PHP variables?

I have checked some answers about passing variables from python to php and vice-versa but I did not understand.
If the communication between php, python and shell can be optimised please inform me.
Thank You!

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497540/how-to-call-a-python-script-from-php showed how to call python from php (http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) and get all return values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there ;) you can always combine the 2 keys into one string with a delimiter inbetween.

```
#!/home/user/Desktop/generate_keys.py

from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random

random_generator = Random.new().read
key = RSA.generate(1024,random_generator)
public_key = key.publickey().exportKey()               #export public key
private_key = key.exportKey()                          #export private key

data = public_key + "||" + private_key
print(data)
```

so when you receive the data in php you can just use [`explode(delimiter, string)`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) .

```
<?php

   $command = escapeshellcmd('python3 generate_keys.py');
   $keys = shell_exec($command);
   $splitted_keys = explode("||", $keys);
   echo $splitted_keys[0];

?>
```

Comment: Thank You that solved my problem xD
But Can you tell me some way to pass variables in between them ?

Comment: you can always use the command line arguments to [communicate with python.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-command-line-arguments-argv-example/) `sys.argv` is an array of items grabbed from the cmd after python3. (read the link, it has a more comprehensive explanation)