# What is the fastest way to execute Python from PHP?

Tags: php, python, shell

What is the fastest way to execute Python from PHP assuming that I need to pass variables to Python script and get result from it?

Comment: You could communicate between the two with a message queue.

Comment: not sure about fastest, but here are two ways: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041104/execute-python-from-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the <kbd>[popen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php)</kbd> function:

```
$result = popen('python yourscript.py ' . $args, 'r');
```