# PHP behind Python

Tags: php, python, nginx

I know a lot about python but I don't know all the aspect to php would it be possible to run python and have it out put code to php then to nginx and then to the client. Now I do realize that this is somewhat counter productive (so please do not post about how this is a bad idea) but I was just curious if this was possible at all...?

Comment: yes. `exec`. but that's all i know.

Comment: Oh wow yeah python could run the code through php wow duh :] thanks!

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166944/calling-python-in-php

Comment: @yoda that is actually the exact opposite of what I wanted ahaha thanks to Cole I remembered php can be called from command line (with python)

Comment: This sounds like a web service to me. Have you considered spitting values out of PHP as JSON and then sending the JSON to Python to NGINX etc. - http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServices. This would also allow you to sanitize the output from one to another.

Comment: I had not considered that good idea :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Cole Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350209/) I remembered that you can just call php after writing to the dynamic.php file and retrieving the output using `subprocess` then send the returned code to nginx to the client (yes this may be about twice the time) but if you are looking for a super secure way of running php code this might be an idea. Have python parse the code before running it so all calls that are not "in legal" legal being a list will be commented out or returned as an error.