# including python code in php

Tags: php, python

I want to include the following python code into php. The name of the python file is hello.py. The contents are
print "Hello World"
I want to call this python script in php and show the same in webpage

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a python script from PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166944/calling-python-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible like that. What you could do is use `exec` or `passthru` to run the python in the terminal and return the results. Best option would be to do a separate call to the python script and combine them on the client.