# How to pass php (CI) value python script of raspberry pi and get result

Tags: php, python, codeigniter, raspberry-pi

I have a python code running getting values from a raspberry pi. I want  passed php (CI) value to the python script for run raspberry pi and how to get python result in php (CI).

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166944/calling-python-in-php

Comment: You can use command line to execute your python script. Take a look at the [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function.