# Execute Python Script From PHP Script

Tags: php, python

I have python file which is newtry.py and this is my code:

```
print ("hello world")
```

I also have php file which is importKeyword.php and this is my code:

```
<?php
$python = `python newtry.py`;
echo $python;
echo "yes";
 ?>
```

I want to print "hello world" from python in the browser but it only print "yes" which is from php file. I have look at this solution which is using backquote operator ( [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18921091/7292205) ) and wondering why I can't make it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exec function

```
exec('python newtry.py', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: I have try this one before and it print (array(0) { })

Comment: @nurin Then you did something wrong. Add that attempt to your question and we might be able to help you with it

Comment: try set full path to python

Answer (score 0):

use `2>&1` to redirect the output

```
<?php
exec("python newtry.py 2>&1", $python);
print_r($python);
echo "yes";
?>
```

Comment: The output display this one : (Array ( [0] => python: can't open file 'newtry.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory ) yes )

Comment: check if the `newtry.py` is exist in current dir