# possible to use Excel or Python in wordpress?

Tags: python, excel, wordpress

I'm trying to create a complex calculator on my blog, I have my own custom domain and I ran wordpress on it.

I was thinking to create the calculator in either Excel or Python, have an interface on my blog so I can input variables from my blog page, then the back-end program calculates and display output on the blog page.

Is this even possible? Or is there any wordpress plugin allows such things? I currently use Calculated Fields Form but don't think it allows me to implement anything too complex.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use python in your wordpres. see the below question, I think it will help you.
[Calling Python in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166944/calling-python-in-php)