# Can't run python code from PHP- No output

Tags: php, python

This is what my file Final2.py looks like. It gives the output when run alone. I want to access this from a PHP file as a part of my project.

The PHP file that should run this code looks like this:

```
<?php 
$command = escapeshellcmd('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/FinalProject/Final2.py'); 
$output = shell\_exec($command);
echo $output; 
?>
```

```
#!/usr/bin/pytho
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import random as rd
from collections import defaultdict
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import mysql.connector

def calculate(): 
   dataset=pd.read_csv('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/FinalProject/Mall_Customers.csv')
   X = dataset.iloc[:, [3, 4]].values
   m=X.shape[0]
   _n=X.shape[1] 
   K=5 
   Centroids=np.array([]).reshape(2,0)
   _i=0
   for _i in range(K):
     rand=rd.randint(0,m)
     Centroids=np.c_[Centroids,X[rand]]
   num_iter=100
   for _n in range(num_iter):
    #step 2.a
     EuclidianDistance=np.array([]).reshape(m,0)
     for k in range(K):
        tempDist=np.sum((X-Centroids[:,k])**2,axis=1)
        EuclidianDistance=np.c_[EuclidianDistance,tempDist]
     C=np.argmin(EuclidianDistance,axis=1)+1

   return C

ret=calculate()
print(ret)
```

Comment: This question has already answered here ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166944/calling-python-in-php

Comment: Does it work if you remove the backslash (`\ `) when calling shell_exec()?

Comment: It is not working

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the PHP function you are using is miss_spelled try the following code:

```
<?php 
$command = 
escapeshellcmd('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/FinalProject/Final2.py'); 
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output; 
?>
```

Comment: Still no luck :(